# R: Summary statistics for groups / subsets within panel data - code and layout

Tags: r, layout, output, summary, group

I have the following data (posted in the comment):

Now I would like to have summary statistics. I only need the mean and the number of observations. The summary statistics should be grouped according to the rating of the product and there should be a difference in means test for the means of the ratings 1 and 5. In the end it should look like this:

[image: Desired layout / output of summary statistics]

I came across the describeBy function. However, the problem there is that I could not end up with my desired layout (see picture) and I could not include the difference in the means test for the means of the rating 1 and 5 and the means for the whole sample.

Further, I also tried to use the stargazer package. But there I had similar problems.

Could anyone help me here?

Comment: My data: ````structure(list(`Product Name` = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B",  "C", "C", "C"), Year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L,  2018L, 2019L, 2020L), Revenue = c(200L, 300L, 200L, 400L, 500L,  300L, 200L, 200L, 300L), Costs = c(50L, 20L, 40L, 30L, 30L, 30L,  20L, 50L, 30L), Age = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L),      Rating = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -9L))````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this dplyr/tidy pipeline:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  group_by(Rating) %>% 
  summarize(mean_Revenue = mean(Revenue),
            mean_Costs = mean(Costs),
            mean_Age = mean(Age),
            Observations=n()
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !Rating) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "name",names_from = Rating,values_from = value,names_glue = "Rating{.name}") %>% 
  mutate(`Anova F-Test (p-value)` = c(sapply(dt %>% select(Revenue:Age), function(y) anova(lm(y~dt$Rating))$`Pr(>F)`[[1]]),NA)) %>% 
  left_join(
    dt %>%  
      pivot_longer(cols=Revenue:Age) %>% 
      group_by(name = paste0("mean_",name)) %>% 
      summarize(Total_means=mean(value))
  )
```

Output:

```
  name         Rating1 Rating2 Rating3 Rating4 Rating5 `Anova F-Test (p-value)` Total_means
  <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>                    <dbl>       <dbl>
1 mean_Revenue     200   400       250     300     200                    0.742       289. 
2 mean_Costs        45    26.7      40      30      20                    0.196        33.3
3 mean_Age           2     3         4       4       2                    0.552         3  
4 Observations       2     3         2       1       1                   NA            NA
```

#### Updated 4/22/22

- Original answer did not limit the anova to Ratings 1 and 5

```
# small function to get anova
get_anova <-function(y,rating, ratings=c(1,5)) {
  y_ = y[rating %in% ratings]
  x_ = rating[rating %in% ratings]
  anova(lm(y_~x_))$`Pr(>F)`[[1]]
}

dt %>%
  group_by(Rating) %>% 
  summarize(mean_Revenue = mean(Revenue),
            mean_Costs = mean(Costs),
            mean_Age = mean(Age),
            Observations=n()
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !Rating) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "name",names_from = Rating,values_from = value,names_glue = "Rating{.name}") %>% 
  mutate(anova = c(sapply(dt %>% select(Revenue:Age), function(y) get_anova(y,rating=dt$Rating)),NA)) %>% 
  left_join(
    dt %>%  
      pivot_longer(cols=Revenue:Age) %>% 
      group_by(name = paste0("mean_",name)) %>% 
      summarize(Total_means=mean(value))
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code! When I tried to run it, I got an error message saying "error in summarize (., mean_Revenue = mean(Revenue), mean_Costs = mean(Costs), : Argument "by" is missing, with no default. I have the tidyverse package installed and also in the library. What do I need to change in order to be able to run the code?

Comment: it is possible you have some other package that also runs `summarize()` which is masking `dplyr::summarize()`,  Try rerunning the code above, but with package specified, like this: `dt %>% group_by(Rating) %>% dplyr::summarize(....)`

Comment: Dear langtang, I would have a follow-up question: In your code above where you write function(y) anova(lm(y~dt$Rating))$`Pr(>F)`[[1]]),NA)), does [1]]),NA) reflect on the one hand the Rating 1 and on the other hand the Rating NA? Or how do I need to interpret the [1]]),NA part?

Comment: the `NA` is being added to the result of sapply, which itself only returns three values.  this is in a mutate call, on a frame with four rows, so if i only return the three results from sapply i will get an error. so i add an `NA` to make it four.  look closely, and you will see that the NA and the sapply result are wrapped in `c()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! But where in the code then can I see that I calculate the Anova F-Test p-value for the differences in the means of Rating 1 and Rating 5?

Comment: No where. I didn't limit to 1 and 5 - see my updated answer

Comment: Why did you choose Anove F-Test and not t-test if I may ask?

Comment: its the same test if there are only two groups. If you wanted to have more than two groups, you could set the `ratings` param of the `get_anova()` to something like `c(1,5,4)` and the code would still work. If I had used the t-test, the code would fail if you changed the `ratings` param from its default (1,5) to something with more than two groups

Comment: please note, none of this make sense with the small dataset you have. I hope you have substantially more data than what you are showing in the small dataset

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank you for that. So when I only compare two groups like the group with Rating 1 and the group with Rating 5, it doesn't matter which test I do? Yes, my real dataset is much much larger.

Comment: The default treatment of variance equality in R's t.test is to treat the variances as unequal;  to get the identical value between the anova F test of two variables and the t.test, the `var.equal` param of `t.test` would have to be set to `TRUE` (i.e. changed from its default `FALSE`)

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. Could you adjust the code above using the t.test or should I open a new question for that?

Comment: I think you can just change the anova line to `t.test(y_~x_)$p.value`. If you are still struggling, please open a new question

Comment: okay, thank you.